# Area of regular n-gon without trig?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request, area, polygons

As the title suggests I'm trying to find a formula for the area of a regular n-gon that doesn't use trigonometry. I already know the trig formula and I realize that my question is simply asking for how to convert this into non-trig form. I know it will involve some kind of infinite summation but I have no clue how to work it out. The n-gon is inscribed in a circle of radius b (say). Please don't use b=1 if you help me because I want to see how b enters into the formula.

Thanks

Comment: If we find the answer $A$ for a circle of radius $1$, then the answer for a circle of radius $b$ is $b^2 A$, by scaling.

Comment: If you have $b$ set to 1 in your formula, then if someone gives you a formula for a regular n-gon inscribed in a circle of radius 1 all you have to do is multiply by $b^2$ and this will give you the formula for general regular n-gon inscribed in a circle of radius $b$.

Comment: If you have formulas in terms of trig then you can use truncated infinite series for trig-related functions and get your (approximate) answer that way. This seems to be consistent with what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Area of regular $n$-gon in terms of circumradius $b$ is $$A=\frac{1}{2} nb^2 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right),$$so to avoid the sine function expand in a taylor series: $$A=\frac{1}{2} nb^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the formula
uses the sin function,
it has to be there
in some form.

If you want to compute
the area of a 2n-gon
in terms of the area
of a n-gon,
you can use the method 
of Archimedes,
which is described very nicely
in chapter 38 of
"100 Great Problems of
Elementary Mathematics"
by Heinrich Dorrie
($13 from Amazon,
also available online
from Google Play Books).
I highly recommend this book.

Archimedes' method
uses pure geometry
to go from the
sides of inscribed
and circumscribed
n-gons
to the corresponding
sides of
2n-gons.
Though the method shown
in this book
is used to get
upper and lower bounds
for the circumference of a circle,
it could be readily modified
to get bounds
for the area.